# How to change Qml "model Property" for multiple C++ Models

Tags: c++, qt, qml

the code below shows two C++ QStringListModels.
"model" is integrated into the main.qml file  as "myModel"  and  "model2" is integrated into the windowLoader.qml file as "myModel2".
The View of "MyModel2" is loaded when you click on an item of the View of "myModel".

My Question:
If there would be a "myModelX", is it possible to change the model property from windowLoader.qml which has the value "myModel2" or do I have to write a windowLoader.qml for every Model? 

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QStringListModel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    QStringListModel model;
    model.setStringList( QStringList() << "foo" << "bar" << "baz" );

    QStringListModel model2;
    model2.setStringList( QStringList() << "a"  << "b"  << "c" );

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlContext *context = engine.rootContext();

    context->setContextProperty( "myModel", &model );
    context->setContextProperty( "myModel2", &model2);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("StringList")


    Loader {
        id: windowLoader
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: myModel
        delegate: Rectangle {
          id: rec1
          property alias text: text_field.text
          color: "green"
          border.color: "lightgreen"
          radius: 8
          width: 100
          height: 20
          MouseArea {
              anchors.fill: parent
              onClicked: windowLoader.setSource( "qrc:/windowLoader.qml",
                                                { "title_text":
                                                   rec1.text } )
          }
          Text {
              id:text_field
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: display


            }
        }
    }
}
```

windowLoader.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0


Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr(title_text + "-Window")

    property string title_text

    ListView {

        anchors.fill: parent
        model: myModel2
        delegate: Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
            border.color: "lightsteelblue"
            radius: 8
            width: 100
            height: 20
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: display
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not pass the model as a context-property like you do with `title_text`? (just pick a generic name that doesn't clash)

Comment: That is the reason why I asked this Question.
I don't think that this is possible because the value of the qml model property is not a basic type.

Comment: You can do that, it will be the `var` or `object` type

Comment: Than I think I understand what you're after. Do you want to specify a string context property which is used in WindowLoader.qml to get a model? If so, you can put all the QStringListModel's in one rootContext property (say `"models"`, which is a QQmlPropertyMap or a class with Q_PROPERTY) and get them by `models[modelname]`

Comment: Yes that is exactly what  I want ...
 but you can't insert Models into a   QQmlPropertyMap ... or?

Comment: From C++ you can: [detailed description](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlpropertymap.html#details).